# how to print the checked items from the checked listbox to a label in c#?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I'm Trying to fetch items from checked listbox when the user checks the listbox item it should be displayed in a label on a button click. I tried using this:

```
foreach (object item in checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems)
{
    labelto.Text += checkedlistbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
 List that this enumerator is bound to has been found, enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.
```

How to print the checked items from the checked listbox to a label?

Comment: which line shows the error

Comment: @un-lucky I have used a messagebox to print the exception hence it is not showing me the line no :(

Comment: If the idea is to display the check items in `Label` then why are you using the `SelectedItem` inside the loop?  The whole point of a `foreach` is to access each item in a list and the item is accessed via the loop control variable inside the loop.  Your loop control variable is `item` so why are you not using that at all inside the loop?

Comment: @DragandDrop what data type am I supposed to use instead of object?

Comment: Based of your datasource, simpliest solution will be `var displayText = String.Join(", ", checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray());`.

Comment: Please share your whole code. The exception states your editing the bound checklist collection. Your arent't changing the collection in your given snippet.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complicated task, why don't you make try with the following:

```
string displayText = "";
foreach(object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
     DataRowView castedItem = item as DataRowView;
     displayText += castedItem["boundPropertyNameHere"];  
}
labelto.Text = displayText;
```

Please note:

- Where `boundPropertyNameHere` be the name of property that used to bind the collection.

Comment: what would boundedPropertyNameHere be in my case? sorry, I'm new to C#.

Comment: @BlackPanther: that depends on how you populate `checkedlistbox1`, probably the `DisplayMember = "whatyougavehere"`

Comment: I'm fetching items in the listbox from the database, mySql to be specific.

Comment: I refered this link [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTrw04aEAXM)..

Comment: @BlackPanther, This is the solution for real data. For bogus data like a Array of string. A toString is enought even if it make no sense for any other case.